# How to handle API callback response in Rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json, api, post, callback

In a rails 3 app, I'm using a third party API to save webcam videos. When a video is saved to their server, they give an option to send you a callback to a url you specify. From their site:

---

Callback

Callbacks are for advanced users who wish to be notified when a video is finished processing on the Framey servers. If you choose to receive callbacks in your account settings Framey will POST video and thumbnail URLs to your server once conversion is complete.

Here's an example of the data that we post to your server:

```
"video": {  
  "name": "ecf7c330-549c-012e-9d34-7c6d628c53d4",        
  "filesize": 123456,       
  "duration": 15.62,        
  "state": "uploaded",              
  "views": 0,    
  "data": {
    "my_user_id": 1,
    "video_title": "Contest Submission"
  },
  "flv_url": "http://framey.com/videos/source/ecf7c330-549c-012e-9d34-7c6d628c53d4.flv",
  "mp4_url": "http://framey.com/videos/source/ecf7c330-549c-012e-9d34-7c6d628c53d4.mp4",
  "large_thumbnail_url": "http://framey.com/thumbnails/large/ecf7c330-549c-012e-9d34-7c6d628c53d4.jpg",
  "medium_thumbnail_url": "http://framey.com/thumbnails/medium/ecf7c330-549c-012e-9d34-7c6d628c53d4.jpg",
  "small_thumbnail_url": "http://framey.com/thumbnails/small/ecf7c330-549c-012e-9d34-7c6d628c53d4.jpg"
}
```

---

I'm working my way to understanding how to handle this, but I thought I could get proper direction from you good folks. They specify a POST method, so I have to set up a route. In my config/routes.rb file I have

```
post "framey/callback/"
```

In my app/controllers/framey_controller.rb file there is this:

```
class FrameyController < ApplicationController
  def callback
  end
end
```

Do I need to do something like

```
render :json =>????
```

I'm familiar with using POST via HTML forms and/or ajax. I'm not sure how to grab the JSON they send back to me.

Thanks in advance for the help and please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this -- Framey is a pain to test callbacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In app/controllers/framey_controller.rb

```
class FrameyController < ApplicationController
  def callback
    v = Video.new
    v.name = params[:video][:name]
    v.user_id = params[:video][:data][:user_id]
    v.question_id = params[:video][:data][:question_id]
    v.save
  end
end
```